# Unsatisfied dependencies for type [PartitionManager] with qualifiers [@Default]?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, cdi

I'm trying to create a simple enterprise application that makes use of PicketLink JPA IDM for user management.  My structure is as follows:

Application EAR
  -- Web app (WAR)
  -- EJB (JAR)

The PicketLink libraries are available as modules on JBoss EAP 6.1.

I'm trying to simply `@Inject` the `PartitionManager`, but keep receiving errors.  I've tried injecting it into EJBs and POJOs, both with the same results.  In my WAR, I've got a simple action class that looks like this:

```
@Named
public class TestAction {

  @Inject
  private PartitionManager partitionManager = null;

  public void runTest() {
  if (partitionManager == null) {
  System.err.println("NULL");
  } else {
  System.out.println("NOT NULL");
  }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to deploy this class I get the following error:

```
[0m[31m21:15:47,527 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyTest.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyTest.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [PartitionManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private net.test.web.servlets.TestAction.partitionManager]
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:311)
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:280)
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:143)
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:163)
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:382)
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:367)
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:64)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
  ... 3 more
```

I've tried `@Inject`ing both the `PartitionManager` and the `IdentityManager`, both leading to the same results.  Can anyone explain why this error is occurring?  Is there something else I need to do to create the `PartitionManager` or `IdentityManager`?

Comment: beans.xml in the correct location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though it was an issue with the PicketLink module as created by the PicketLink Installer.  There is a small bug that was causing it to not be configured correctly within JBoss EAP 6.1.  Packaging the JARs in the EAR file worked with no problem.